# Using printf when string has backslash

Tags: bash, prompt, printf

I'm trying to both `printf` and `export` the variable used for setting `PS1` but everything I've tried returns error in `printf` or puts literal `\u` in prompt.

```
v='\u\$'; printf "$v"; export PS1="$v"
-bash: printf: missing unicode digit for \u

v='\\u\$'; printf "$v"; export PS1="$v"
\u$

v=$'\u'; v+='\$'; printf "${v}"; export PS1="${v}"
-bash: printf: missing unicode digit for \u
```

Is there a way to format `$v` to make both `printf` and `export` work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This fails since `printf` interprets some backslashed letters in its first argument as special.

In general when using `printf` you supply

1. A static formatting string, possibly containing placeholders for data that should be taken from the other arguments, and
2. Other variable data to be used in the placeholders in the static formatting string.

This means that the first argument to `printf` can *always* be a single quoted string.

In the shell, you may use just `%s` as a placeholder for virtually anything in the formatting string, unless you want things like left/right padding (e.g. `%20s` to use 20 characters for a right-justified string, or `%-20s` for a left-justified string), a certain number of decimal places in floats (`%.3f` for three decimal places), or zero-filling of integers (`%08d` for eight digits, zero-filled) etc.

For example, to print your string, use `%s` in the formatting string:

```
v='\u\$'
printf 'PS1 will be set to "%s"\n' "$v"   # or just:  printf '%s\n' "$v"
PS1="$v"
```

or

```
PS1='\u\$'
printf 'PS1 was set to "%s"\n' "$PS1"   # or just:  printf '%s\n' "$PS1"
```

This will output

```
PS1 will be set to "\u\$"
```

and

```
PS1 was set to "\u\$"
```

See `printf(1)` and/or `printf(3)` on your system (`man 1 printf` and `man 3 printf`).

---

Note, too, that `PS1` will not need to be exported.